# Efficient way to get the minimal tuple from a set of columns in polars

Tags: python, sorting, python-polars

What is the most efficient way in polars to do this:

```py
import polars as pl
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.default_rng()

df = pl.DataFrame([
    pl.Series('a', rng.normal(size=10_000_000)),
    pl.Series('b', rng.normal(size=10_000_000)),
])

df.sort(['a', 'b']).head(1)
```

I.e. I want to find the smallest tuple of numbers (a, b) based on lexicographical ordering. Finding the minimum does not require a full sort, so the above code is very inefficient. I tried

```py
df.lazy().sort(['a', 'b']).head(1).collect()
```

but this does not lead to a significant speedup. Creating a single column of type `pl.Struct` does not help either since polars does not seem to define a notion of ordering on structs.

#### Update

Thanks to the answer from ΩΠΟΚΕΚΡΥΜΜΕΝΟΣ I have now settled for the following solution:

```py
def lexicographic_min(df):
    columns = list(df.columns)
    for col in columns:
        if df.select(pl.col(col).is_null().any()).row(0)[0]:
            df = df.filter(pl.col(col).is_null())
        else:
            df = df.filter(pl.col(col) == pl.col(col).min())
    return df.row(0)

def lexicographic_max(df):
    columns = list(df.columns)
    for col in columns:
        df = df.filter(pl.col(col) == pl.col(col).max())
    return df.row(0)
```

This version handles null values by considering them 'smaller' than any non-null values and does not require any invocations of `.sort()`.

Answer (score 3):

One easy speedup is to perform the filtering in successive steps.  So starting with this data:

```py
import polars as pl
import numpy as np
import time

rng = np.random.default_rng()
size = 100_000_000
df = pl.DataFrame([
    pl.Series('a', rng.normal(size=size)),
    pl.Series('b', rng.normal(size=size)),
])
df
```

```
shape: (100000000, 2)
┌──────────┬───────────┐
│ a        ┆ b         │
│ ---      ┆ ---       │
│ f64      ┆ f64       │
╞══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 0.691714 ┆ 0.042488  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1.328573 ┆ -0.125364 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ -0.23431 ┆ -0.463718 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0.383145 ┆ -0.307686 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...      ┆ ...       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0.12102  ┆ -0.046244 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0.556771 ┆ 0.208904  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0.665356 ┆ 1.825813  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0.660261 ┆ 0.577974  │
└──────────┴───────────┘
```

Here are two timings of interest.  The first is from the original post:

```py
start = time.perf_counter()
df.sort(['a', 'b']).head(1)
print(time.perf_counter() - start)
```

```
>>> df.sort(['a', 'b']).head(1)
shape: (1, 2)
┌───────────┬───────────┐
│ a         ┆ b         │
│ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ f64       ┆ f64       │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ -5.567192 ┆ -0.658551 │
└───────────┴───────────┘
>>> print(time.perf_counter() - start)
2.884132520000094
```

Versus successive filtering...

```py
start = time.perf_counter()
(
    df
    .filter(pl.col('a') == pl.col('a').min())
    .filter(pl.col('b') == pl.col('b').min())
)
print(time.perf_counter() - start)
```

```
>>> start = time.perf_counter()
>>> (
...     df
...     .filter(pl.col('a') == pl.col('a').min())
...     .filter(pl.col('b') == pl.col('b').min())
... 
... )
shape: (1, 2)
┌───────────┬───────────┐
│ a         ┆ b         │
│ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ f64       ┆ f64       │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ -5.567192 ┆ -0.658551 │
└───────────┴───────────┘
>>> print(time.perf_counter() - start)
0.10943432300018685
```

##### Edit: Null values

This is a bit of a workaround ... but if you need to consider `null` values as the minimum (and still want to keep the performance) , we can do the following.

Let's say we have the following data:

```py
rng = np.random.default_rng()
size = 100_000_000
null_count = 100_000
df = pl.DataFrame(
    [
        pl.Series("a", rng.normal(size=size))
        .extend_constant(None, null_count)
        .shuffle(seed=1),
        pl.Series("b", rng.normal(size=size))
        .extend_constant(None, null_count)
        .shuffle(seed=2),
    ]
)
df
```

```
shape: (100100000, 2)
┌───────────┬───────────┐
│ a         ┆ b         │
│ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ f64       ┆ f64       │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ -0.336999 ┆ 0.230278  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ -0.654095 ┆ -0.056833 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0.195498  ┆ -1.239257 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0.490639  ┆ -0.098735 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...       ┆ ...       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1.077227  ┆ 1.387681  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ -1.75284  ┆ 0.043309  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ -0.910276 ┆ -0.762231 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ -0.784335 ┆ 0.286225  │
└───────────┴───────────┘
```

We can sort after the filter step.  This should allow you to keep most of the gains in performance (depending on the proportion of `null` values you have in your data).

```py
start = time.perf_counter()
(
    df
    .filter(pl.col('a').is_null() | (pl.col('a') == pl.col('a').min()))
    .sort('a').filter(pl.col('a') == pl.col('a').first())
    .filter(pl.col('b').is_null() | (pl.col('b') == pl.col('b').min()))
    .sort('b').filter(pl.col('b') == pl.col('b').first())
    .head(1)
)
print(time.perf_counter() - start)
```

```
shape: (1, 2)
┌──────┬──────┐
│ a    ┆ b    │
│ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ f64  ┆ f64  │
╞══════╪══════╡
│ null ┆ null │
└──────┴──────┘
>>> print(time.perf_counter() - start)
0.1509907710023981
```

For comparison to the `sort` alone ....

```
>>> start = time.perf_counter()
>>> df.sort(['a', 'b']).head(1)
shape: (1, 2)
┌──────┬──────┐
│ a    ┆ b    │
│ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ f64  ┆ f64  │
╞══════╪══════╡
│ null ┆ null │
└──────┴──────┘
>>> print(time.perf_counter() - start)
3.319076051997399
```

It's definitely not elegant ... but (depending on your data), it may still retain most of the performance gains.

Comment: Thanks. That's a very neat trick. However, the behaviour is different if we have NULL values in the columns a or b. The only way I can see to fix that is to explicitly check the value of `pl.col('a').min()` and filter with `is_null()` instead if it is NULL.

Comment: I've added a workaround that may still give you significant performance gains if you need to consider `null` values as minimum values.

Comment: Thanks again. Actually, I think there is a solution with the 'correct' behaviour for null values which does not need any invocations of `.sort()`. See the update to my question.